# User custom private data in AVPacket

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to attach some user private data to `AVPacket` before decoding to be able to match input `AVPacket` and decoded output `AVFrame`? Some sort of `AVFrame::opaque`.

Specifically, decoding process of h264 codestream can do reorder in a case B-frames are present and I would like to identify which `AVPacket` was decoded to which `AVFrame`.

Comment: There is a side_data member in the AVPacket struct. Add a metadata dictionary entry in there with a value as string. Look for it in the AVFrame

Comment: Is it possible to add side data to AVPacket while encoding and use it while decoding ? @Gyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Gyan I was able to solve the issue with the following code in the main decoding loop.

```cpp
static uint64_t privateId = 0;

// Allocate dictionary and add appropriate key/value record
AVDictionary * frameDict = NULL;
av_dict_set(&frameDict, "private_id", std::to_string(privateId++).c_str(), 0);

// Pack dictionary to be able to use it as a side data in AVPacket
int frameDictSize = 0;
uint8_t *frameDictData = av_packet_pack_dictionary(frameDict, &frameDictSize);

// Free dictionary not used any more
av_dict_free(&frameDict);

// Add side_data to AVPacket which will be decoded
av_packet_add_side_data(&avPacket, AVPacketSideDataType::AV_PKT_DATA_STRINGS_METADATA, frameDictData, frameDictSize);

// Do the actual decoding
...

// Free side data from packet
av_packet_free_side_data(&avPacket);

// Obtain privateId from decoded frame
uint64_t privateId = std::stoul(av_dict_get(avFrame->metadata, "private_id", NULL, 0)->value);

// Free dictionary from decoded frame
av_dict_free(&avFrame->metadata);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add side data to AVPacket while encoding and use it while decoding ?